# Data List Control text Search

Tags: c#, css, datalist

I have a datalist control thats being populated by a data source in the following way:
I want to check if Customer type has values like R,P,Y and if Yes I just want to bold the CutomerName part of the whole text in the give below datalist control..Please guide me on this ..Thank You

```
<asp:DataList ID="Customer" runat="server" 
    DataSourceID="CustomerIndicatorSource" RepeatColumns="2" 
    DataKeyField="CustomerIndicatorID" Width="100%" 
    onitemdatabound="CustomerIndicators_ItemDataBound" 
    style="font-size:x-small; line-height:normal"> 

    <ItemTemplate>                             
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat ="server" Text='<%# Eval("CustomerType") + Eval("CustomerName") %>' Width="300px"></asp:Label> 
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your onitemdatabound method CustomerIndicators_ItemDataBound you should be able to check the value of the item being bound, get the Label, and edit based on that.  This has not been tested, but it should give you a general idea of how to go about doing this.

```
  void CustomerIndicators_ItemDataBound (Object sender, DataListItemEventArgs e)
  {

 if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || 
     e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
 {
    Label CustomerTypeLabel = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("Label1");

    DataRowView drv= ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).ToString();
    string CustomerType = drv.Row["CustomerType"].ToString();

    switch(CustomerType){
    case "R":
    case "P":
    case "Y":
          CustomerTypeLabel.Font.Bold = true;
          break;

    }

 }
```

These links have additional information.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6y92e1ze(v=vs.85).aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowview%28v=vs.110%29.aspx